# PHP/MySQL Convert and save formatted prices

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, decimal, price

I need store in MySQL all prices submitted by users. The prices submitted by the users can contain these formats:

```
 123.456,78  (ARG format)
 123,456.78  (US format)
  123456,78  (ARG simplified format)
  123456.78  (US simplified format)
```

In MySQL i have a column named "price" of type `decimal`.

My question is, How can i convert those formats to `decimal` to save them in my database?, or, How can i convert values to "ARG simplified format" to save all as `varchar`? I need all with the same format (two decimals).

Comment: Why negative votes? Explain your reasons...

Comment: Why don't you limit the user input so you can format the currency as soon as the user types ? PS:I didn't down vote you. Also, and because you're a new stack user, make sure you read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). GL

Comment: This is an application problem.  It would be clumsy to try to do it in SQL.  Think of it this way:  a database is for data; formatting (incoming or outgoing) should be handled by the application.  (No, I did not downvote you either.)

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to help you with [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36749482/convert-currency-string-to-decimal-php/), that is similar to this one.

My solution is to limit/format the user input on the client side, for that you can use the `html5` input `type=number` with a `step` (increment) of `0.01`.

```html
    <input type="number" step="0.01" value='0.00' placeholder='0.00'>
```

---

**Notes:**

Make sure you validate the values on the server side too.

Comment: yes, sorry but in the previous question i expressed wrong, @PedroLobito have reason. Is not easy for me write in english, sorry.

This is a solution, but in my country, decimal is separated by a comma (but this is not a problem). I avoided this solution because I had everything planned to use the other format. But I think that not have other solution. Thanks